# How can I change the stock in a Microsoft Access database?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access

I'm having a problem altering the stock in my database. What I am looking to do is to minus the stock in my database by 1 when the button 'Reserve Item' is clicked on. So say the stock is sitting at 10. When I reserve an item I want the stock in the database to automatically decrease to 9.

Any ideas on how this can be achieved Using ASP.NET with C#?

Comment: You should consider not using Access with a web site.

Answer (score 2):

Even shorter:

```
update stock_table
set stock_quantity = stock_quantity - 1
where stock_id = xxx
```

Answer (score 0):

[The SQL UPDATE statement](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

What you really want to do is something like this:

```
UPDATE stock_table 
SET stock_quantity = (SELECT stock_quantity - 1 FROM stock_table WHERE stock_id = '#####')
WHERE stock_id = '#####'
```

`'######'` presents the id of your item (not sure if you are using int or varchar/text or guid).

Comment: Why the extra select when you can just do: `SET stock_quantity = stock_quantity - 1`